# Invalid Postback On Server Populated DropDownLists

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I've seen multiple variations of this question asked, but all of the answers seem to involve javascript.

I'm querying a database, retrieving a list of items, and populating 3 different dropdown lists with the exact same content. After I select an item from a list, and click the "Save" button, I get an invalid postback error.

I'm certain it's because I'm using AutoPostBack on my DropDownList to trigger an update and disable a new selection in the other lists. When I set AutoPostBack to false, the error disappears.

I've read that I need to register my list content for event validation, but the examples I'm seeing, as mentioned above, are manually entered or handled with javascript; not server side from content generated by a DB query.

The solution I'm using now is a "link button" instead of a regular asp:button, since the former does not seem to cause a postback.

I would like to know if there is a more formal way of handling this. I'm not going to disable event validation, for security reasons.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="DropDownListPanel" runat="server" 
ChildrenAsTriggers="true" ><ContentTemplate>

<asp:gridview GridLines="Both" runat="server" 
ShowHeader="false" ShowFooter="true" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>       

   <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Height="100%" ItemStyle-Width="25%">
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckItem">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </Columns>
 </asp:gridview>

 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>



<asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save"
Enabled="True" OnClick="SaveTable"  />
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: your code please, especially the aspx page attributes

Comment: There's the aspx code. Is that helpful?